# How to curl a POST endpoint with a protobuf payload

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java

I have a POST endpoint in my Java service that expects a protobuf 3 payload. This service is used by other services which send the protobuf payload. I would like to do some debugging and send a protobuf payload to the service via a `curl` command, however, I have no idea how to construct such a payload, given it's a binary protocol.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [protoCURL](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl) for this purpose. It's a command-line tool to send and receive protobuf HTTP REST requests while writing them in the Protobuf [Text](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl#protobuf-text-format) or [JSON](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl#protobuf-json-format) format.

A request could look something like this:

```
protocurl -I path/to/protos -i ..MyRequest -o ..MyResponse \
  -u http://host/path/o/endpoint -d 'someField: "some-string", someIntField: 42'
```

And the response may look like this:

```
=========================== Request Text     =========================== >>>
someField: "my-string"
someIntField: 42
=========================== Response Text    =========================== <<<
someResponseField: "The answer for everything!"
someOtherResonseMessage: {
  fooEnum: BAR
}
```

You can find more examples for how to use it in the [repository](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md).

(Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool and created it, because I had the same problem and needed a better tool.)

Comment: Wonderful tool!